# Not enable to make a where clause after a Left join using subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2016

When i try to make a sub-query with a `left join` i got an error here's an example.

```
Select * FROM ( SELECT Code,Column2 FROM T1) TSubQuery, Table2 T2
Left join Table3 T3
On T3.Code = TSubQuery.Code  --  <== Error triggered
Where TSubQuery.Code= T2.Code
```

this code will triggered the following error :

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 The multi-part identifier
>   "TSubQuery.Code" could not be bound.

So i solved this problem by changing my `Where` into a `Inner join` clause.

```
Select * FROM ( SELECT Code,Column2 FROM T1) TSubQuery
Left join Table3 T3
On T3.Code = TSubQuery.Code 
Inner join  Table2 T2
On T2.Code = TSubQuery.Code
```

I would like to understand, why I have this error ?

there's an other way to solve it without using an `inner join` or with a `with clause` ?

why I don't have this problem when am I using a normal table or with a  `with table` ?

Example:

```
With TQuery as ( SELECT * FROM T1) 
select * from TQuery, Table2 T2
Left join Table3 T3
On T3.Code = TQuery.Code 
Where TQuery.Code = T2.Code
```

Comment: Don't use Old style, instead use modern join

Comment: Sorry i don't understand  @Sami what's modern join

Comment: Read this https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: @Sami thanks for the advice :)

Comment: What causing the error is `Select * FROM (` cause you have `code` column in both tables

Comment: @Sami You are right but since OP looks confused about "old" syntax I posted a answer to explicit the implicit join error (pun intended) =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first as I say in the comment before, **do not** use [Old-Style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).
What causing the error is that you have the same column name in both table (Code column in your case), and SQL Server will don't know which one you refer too, like you say to me "Esperadoce" and I say which "Esperadoce" you refer to?.

What would be the solution for that?

The solution is using `Aliases` as:

```
SELECT T1.Code AS T1Code, T2.Code AS T2Code From ...
```

Also you have a `Mixed query` with Old and modern style joins, So solution would be:

- Use Columns names with `Aliases` instead of `SELECT *`.
- Use Modern style joins instead of the old style, and do not mix them.

Comment: But why it's work when i don't use SubQuery or replace my subquery with a 'with clause'

Comment: @Esperadoce So your real question is _Why the first Mixed not working, while the second Mixed query work?_ ?

Answer (score 1):

**[Implicit JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)** is the problem here, see the line below

```
 FROM ( SELECT Code,Column2 FROM T1) TSubQuery, Table2 T2
```

and pay attention to

```
TSubQuery, Table2
```

remove that coma and move `table2` to a explicit join. You are mixing the old "deprecated" syntax with "modern" explicit join.

[Deprecation of "Old Style" JOIN Syntax: Only A Partial Thing](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wardpond/archive/2008/09/13/deprecation-of-old-style-join-syntax-only-a-partial-thing.aspx?Redirected=true)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the where clause for join conditions. Do this, [working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4800b/4)

```
SELECT
      *
  FROM
      (
        SELECT
              [Code],
              [Column2]
          FROM
              [dbo].[T1]
      ) TSubQuery
    JOIN
      [dbo].[Table2] T2
        ON TSubQuery.[Code] = T2.[Code]
    LEFT JOIN
      [dbo].[Table3] T3
        ON T3.[Code] = TSubQuery.[Code]
```

The legacy join syntax is obsolete and provided only for backward compatibility. And whats more, it sucks.

Additionally, for what its worth, don't use `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with TSubQuery
as
(
    SELECT Code,Column2 FROM T1
)
Select 
    * 
    FROM TSubQuery
        left join Table2 T2
            on TSubQuery.Code= T2.Code
        Left join Table3 T3
            On T3.Code = TSubQuery.Code
```

Comment: over kill, CTE not required

Comment: you can also use subquery instead

Answer (score 0):

the subquery can be avoided in this way:

```
SELECT Code,Column2 FROM T1 as TSubQuery
Left join Table3 T3
On T3.Code = TSubQuery.Code 
Inner join  Table2 T2
On T2.Code = TSubQuery.Code
```